# bash find: get directory of found file

Tags: shell, find, osx

I have a parent folder named "parent_folder" with a lot of subfolders, in these subfolders is a file named "foo.mp4".

I can find these files easily by doing this:

```
mymacbook:parent_folder username$ find ./ -name "foo.mp4" -exec echo {} \;
```

Now that returns the path of each file, relative to parent_folder/

```
./path/to/foo.mp4
```

How can i return just the path, without the filename?

Comment: **man find** (*ACTIONS*): `-printf` `%h` *Leading directories of file's name (all but the last element).  If the file name contains no slashes (since it is in the current directory) the %h specifier expands to "."*.

Comment: Could you show an example of that? Should I put that behind '-exec' or before?

Comment: `find ./ -name "foo.mp4" -printf "%h\n"` will print path to for each found file (one by line). More over as usual nobody use `-exec echo {}` therefore there is `-print` (default even omitted) or `printf` action.

Comment: @Costas, `-printf` is GNU-only. The OP's mentioning OS/X (a BSD system).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I didn't know such limitation for OS/X (BSD). Poor poor mac' users!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With `GNU` find:

```
find . -name foo.mp4 -printf '%h\n'
```

With other `find`s, provided directory names don't contain newline characters:

```
find . -name foo.mp4 |
  LC_ALL=C sed 's|/[^/]*$||'
```

Or:

```
find . -name foo.mp4 -exec dirname {} \;
```

though that means forking a process and running one `dirname` command per file.

If you need to run a command on that `path`, you can do (standard syntax):

```
find . -name "featured.mp4" -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    dir=${file%/*}
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis "$dir" featured.webm
  done' sh {} +
```

Though in this case, you may be able to use `-execdir` (a BSD extension also available in GNU `find`), which `chdir()`s to the file's directory:

```
find . -name "featured.mp4" -execdir \
  ffmpeg -i {} -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis . featured.webm \;
```

Beware though that while the GNU implementation of `find` will expand `{}` to `./filename` here, BSD ones expand to `filename`. It's OK here as the filename is passed as argument to an option and is always `featured.mp4` anyway, but for other usages you may have to take into account that the file name may start with `-` or `+` (and be understood as an option by the command) or contain `=` (and be understood as a variable assignment by awk for instance), or other characters causing [this kind of problem with `perl -p/n`](/q/170013) (not all of them fixed by GNU `find`'s `./` prefix though in that case), etc.

Comment: When you apply `find .` , as dirname you will have . instead of entire path.

Comment: Now how would I translate that to this?
`find ./ -name "featured.mp4" -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis [NEED DIRECTORY HERE] featured.webm \;`

I'm using the second suggestion you mentioned.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh, the OP didn't ask for an absolute path, but for the dirname of the the path.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry for vote down.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas. You helped me make an ffmpeg queue/batch

Answer (score 0):

Below command can also be used to fetch just the directory details.

```
find ./ -name "foo.mp4" | rev | cut -d"/" -f2- | rev
```

Comment: It seems a bit excessive to call three external utilities just to trim a string.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `find` with `-exec dirname {} \;` as suggested above for BSD like systems ?