# how to get file path without the filename itself

Tags: find, cd-command, xsel

im trying to find my .csv files then cd into their directory:

```
find Documents/notes -type f -name "*.csv" | head -1 | xsel -b
```

this copies the first file dir into my clipboard and i'd like to then run:

```
cd $(xsel -b)
```

but ofcourse I can't because it's including the filename which isn't a directory.

Is there anyway to omit the filename? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: See [bash find: get directory of found file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180613/bash-find-get-directory-of-found-file) and more specifically [How do I use `find` to go to directory of that file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337457/how-do-i-use-find-to-go-to-directory-of-that-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `bash` shell, enable the `**` pattern (matches like `*`, but also reaches past `/` in pathnames), then expand the pattern `Documents/notes/**/*.csv`, and then `cd` to the directory of the first match:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
set -- Documents/notes/**/*.csv
cd "$(dirname "$1")"    # or: cd "${1%/*}"
```

With `zsh`, which already has the `**` pattern enabled by default, this can be shortened into

```bash
cd Documents/notes/**/*.csv([1]:h)
```

The glob qualifier `([1]:h)` returns the directory name ("h" as in "head of the path") of the first match of the given pattern.  Change this qualifier to `(.[1]:h)` to make the pattern match only regular files (or symbolic links to such files).

Comment: how would i enable the ** pattern?

Comment: @Mathew As I mentioned in the text, the `bash` shell would require `shopt -s globstar`, whereas it would be enabled by default in the `zsh` shell.  If you are using some other shell, you should mention this in your question.

Comment: okay understood thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using only `find` (need `-quit` support):

```
dir=$(find . -name '*.csv' -print -quit)
cd "$(dirname "$dir")"
```

or

```
cd "$(dirname "$(find . -name '*.csv' -print -quit)")"
```

it breaks on the first match.

`-quit` :

> Exit immediately (with return value zero if no errors have occurred). This is different to -prune because -prune only applies to the contents of pruned directories, while -quit simply makes find stop immediately. No child processes will be left running. Any command lines which have been built by -exec ... + or -execdir ... + are invoked before the program is exited. After -quit is executed, no more files specified on the command line will be processed. For example, `find /tmp/foo /tmp/bar -print -quit` will print only `/tmp/foo`.
> One common use of -quit is to stop searching the file system once we have found what we want.

Comment: what do the -print and -quit flags do? cant find docs on them

Comment: https://man.archlinux.org/man/find.1